# How to run twitter popular tags of Spark streaming using scala?

Tags: scala, twitter, streaming, apache-spark

I am new to Spark so please guide.

There are lots of example available related to Spark streaming using Scala.

You could check it out from https://github.com/apache/incubator-spark/tree/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/examples.

I want to run TwitterPopularTags.scala.

I am not able to set the twitter login details for this example.

http://spark.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#linking-with-spark-streaming

I am successfully run the network count example.

But when i execute
`./run-example org.apache.spark.streaming.examples.TwitterPopularTags local[2]` 
 then it will show me authentication failure issue...

I set twitter login details before initializing string context in TwitterPopularTags.scala like

```
 System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerKey", "####");
 System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerSecret", "##");
 System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessToken", "##");
 System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessTokenSecret", "##");
```

Please guide.

Comment: http://spark.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#linking-with-spark-streaming
I am successfully run the network count example.
But when i execute  ./run-example org.apache.spark.streaming.examples.TwitterPopularTags local[2]  then it will show me authentication failure issue...
I set t

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the specific error message or exception that you're receiving?  Also, the AMP Camp 3 Big Data Mini Course has a streaming Twitter example that may be helpful (and includes instructions on generating the appropriate API tokens): http://ampcamp.berkeley.edu/big-data-mini-course/realtime-processing-with-spark-streaming.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the file "twitter4j.properties" into the Spark root directory (e.g. spark-0.8.0-incubating) before you run the Twitter examples.

twitter4j.properties:

```
oauth.consumerKey=***
oauth.consumerSecret=***
oauth.accessToken=***
oauth.accessTokenSecret=***
```

Worked for me on Mac with the Scala examples.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to open the github link  [https://github.com/apache/incubator-spark/tree/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/examples](http://%20https://github.com/apache/incubator-spark/tree/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/examples).

However you could use the below code which worked for me.

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{ Seconds, StreamingContext }
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.{ SparkContext, SparkConf }
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import org.apache.spark.streaming.flume._

/**
 * A Spark Streaming application that receives tweets on certain 
 * keywords from twitter datasource and find the popular hashtags
 * 
 * Arguments: <comsumerKey> <consumerSecret> <accessToken> <accessTokenSecret> <keyword_1> ... <keyword_n>
 * <comsumerKey>        - Twitter consumer key 
 * <consumerSecret>     - Twitter consumer secret
 * <accessToken>        - Twitter access token
 * <accessTokenSecret>  - Twitter access token secret
 * <keyword_1>          - The keyword to filter tweets
 * <keyword_n>          - Any number of keywords to filter tweets
 * 
 * More discussion at stdatalabs.blogspot.com
 * 
 * @author Sachin Thirumala
 */

object SparkPopularHashTags {
  val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[4]").setAppName("Spark Streaming - PopularHashTags")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    sc.setLogLevel("WARN")

    val Array(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret) = args.take(4)
    val filters = args.takeRight(args.length - 4)

    // Set the system properties so that Twitter4j library used by twitter stream
    // can use them to generat OAuth credentials
    System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerKey", consumerKey)
    System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerSecret", consumerSecret)
    System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessToken", accessToken)
    System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessTokenSecret", accessTokenSecret)

    // Set the Spark StreamingContext to create a DStream for every 5 seconds
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(5))
    // Pass the filter keywords as arguements

    //  val stream = FlumeUtils.createStream(ssc, args(0), args(1).toInt)  
    val stream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None, filters)

    // Split the stream on space and extract hashtags 
    val hashTags = stream.flatMap(status => status.getText.split(" ").filter(_.startsWith("#")))

    // Get the top hashtags over the previous 60 sec window
    val topCounts60 = hashTags.map((_, 1)).reduceByKeyAndWindow(_ + _, Seconds(60))
      .map { case (topic, count) => (count, topic) }
      .transform(_.sortByKey(false))

    // Get the top hashtags over the previous 10 sec window
    val topCounts10 = hashTags.map((_, 1)).reduceByKeyAndWindow(_ + _, Seconds(10))
      .map { case (topic, count) => (count, topic) }
      .transform(_.sortByKey(false))

    // print tweets in the currect DStream 
    stream.print()

    // Print popular hashtags  
    topCounts60.foreachRDD(rdd => {
      val topList = rdd.take(10)
      println("\nPopular topics in last 60 seconds (%s total):".format(rdd.count()))
      topList.foreach { case (count, tag) => println("%s (%s tweets)".format(tag, count)) }
    })
    topCounts10.foreachRDD(rdd => {
      val topList = rdd.take(10)
      println("\nPopular topics in last 10 seconds (%s total):".format(rdd.count()))
      topList.foreach { case (count, tag) => println("%s (%s tweets)".format(tag, count)) }
    })

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

**Explanation:**
`setMaster("local[4]")` - Make sure to set master to local mode with at least 2 threads as 1 thread is used for collecting the incoming streams and another thread for processing it.

We count the popular hashtags with the below code:

```
val topCounts60 = hashTags.map((_, 1)).reduceByKeyAndWindow(_ + _, Seconds(60))
      .map { case (topic, count) => (count, topic) }
      .transform(_.sortByKey(false))
```

The above snippet does a word count of the hashtags over the previous 60/10 secs as specified in the `reduceByKeyAndWindow` and sorts them in descending order.

`reduceByKeyAndWindow` is used in case we have to apply transformations on data that is accumulated in the previous stream intervals.

Execute the code by passing the four twitter OAuth tokens as arguments:
[image]

You should see the popular hashtags over every 10/60 second interval.
[image]

You may check similar projects by integrating spark streaming and storm with flume and kafka in the below links:

Spark Streaming:

Spark Streaming part 1: Real time twitter sentiment analysis
http://stdatalabs.blogspot.in/2016/09/spark-streaming-part-1-real-time.html

Spark streaming part 2: Real time twitter sentiment analysis using Flume
http://stdatalabs.blogspot.in/2016/09/spark-streaming-part-2-real-time_10.html

Spark streaming part 3: Real time twitter sentiment analysis using kafka
http://stdatalabs.blogspot.in/2016/09/spark-streaming-part-3-real-time.html

Data guarantees in Spark Streaming with kafka integration
http://stdatalabs.blogspot.in/2016/10/data-guarantees-in-spark-streaming-with.html

Storm:

Realtime stream processing using Apache Storm - Part 1
http://stdatalabs.blogspot.in/2016/09/realtime-stream-processing-using-apache.html

Realtime stream processing using Apache Storm and Kafka - Part 2
http://stdatalabs.blogspot.in/2016/10/real-time-stream-processing-using.html